# Count multiple unique strings in a line

Tags: awk, count, line, unique, repeat

That is my first post. I would like to write a small script to count multiple unique repeats in a line. The text is a DNA sequence [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA), so the text will be combinations of four letters: A, T, G and C.
If one string appears two times, it will be counted twice, and so on.

The unique strings I want to look for are repeats of three AG, GA, CT or TC, that is (AG)3, (GA)3, (CT)3 and (TC)3, respectively. I don't want the program to count repeats of four or more.

Strings to count:

```
AGAGAG
GAGAGA
CTCTCT
TCTCTC
```

Example input file (two columns separated by a tab):

```
Sequence_1    AGAGAG                   
Sequence_2    AGAGAGT                  
Sequence_3    AGAGAGAG                 
Sequence_4    AGAGAT                   
Sequence_5    AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGT      
Sequence_6    AGAGAGTAGAGAG 
Sequence_7    CTCTCTCTCTC  
Sequence_8    TAGAGAGAT                
Sequence_9    TAAGAGAGAAG
```

Desired output:

```
Sequence_1    AGAGAG                   1
Sequence_2    AGAGAGT                  1
Sequence_3    AGAGAGAG                 0
Sequence_4    AGAGAT                   0
Sequence_5    AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG       0
Sequence_6    AGAGAGTAGAGAG            2
Sequence_7    CTCTCTCTCTCAAGAGAG       1 
Sequence_8    TAGAGAGAT                1
Sequence_9    TAAGAGAGAAG              1
```

I have a small one-liner written with awk, but I think it is not specific when matching the strings:

```
awk '{if($1 ~ /AGAGAG/)x++; if($1 ~ /TCTCTC/)x++;if($1 ~ /GAGAGA/)x++;if($1 ~ /CTCTCT/)x++;print x;x=0}' inputfile.tab
```

Thanks so much for your help. All the best, Bernardo

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some inconsistencies in your description and in the sample input and outputs. So this script might not be perfect, but I hope it comes close enough that you can figure out the rest:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

my ($seq, $dna) = split(/\s+/);
my @strings = qw/AG GA CT TC/;
my $count = 0;
foreach my $s (@strings) {
    my ($b, $e) = split(//, $s);
    @matches = $dna =~ m/(?<!$e)($s){3}(?!$b)/g;
    $count += scalar(@matches);
}
print join("\t", $seq, sprintf("%-20s", $dna), $count), "\n";
```

You can use it with:

```
./script.pl < sample.txt
```

For input:

```
Sequence_1    AGAGAG
Sequence_2    AGAGAGT
Sequence_3    AGAGAGAG
Sequence_4    AGAGAT
Sequence_5    AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGT
Sequence_6    AGAGAGTAGAGAG
Sequence_7    CTCTCTCTCTCAAGAGAG
```

It gives:

```
Sequence_1    AGAGAG                1
Sequence_2    AGAGAGT               1
Sequence_3    AGAGAGAG              0
Sequence_4    AGAGAT                0
Sequence_5    AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGT   0
Sequence_6    AGAGAGTAGAGAG         2
Sequence_7    CTCTCTCTCTCAAGAGAG    1
```

How it works:

- Thanks to the `-n` flag in the shebang, the script is executed for each line coming from `stdin`
- `@strings` is the list of strings we are interested in
- For each item in `@strings`, we count the matches

  - `$s` takes on the value of `AG`, `GA`, `CT`, `TC`
  - The expression `(?<!$s)($s){3}(?!$s)` matches 3 consecutive `$s` that is not followed by `$s` and not preceded by `$s`
  - The expression `(?<!$e)($s){3}(?!$b)` matches 3 consecutive `$s` that is not followed by the 1st character of `$s` and not preceded by the 2nd character of `$s`
  - The operation `$x =~ m///g` returns an array of all matches
  - `scalar(@matches)` is the size of the array of all matches, we add it to the count

Comment: Hi janos. Definitely, Sequence_3 must have zero counts. Although it contains the string (GA)3, this one is at the same time inside a (AG)4, so should not be count as positive. Sorry if I didn`t make enough emphasis!

Comment: I modified the script the produce the desired output for your input. But I'm not sure it handles all corner cases. Test it well, and if you find a case that is not handled correctly, then update the sample in your question.

Comment: Hi janos, I added Sequences 8 and 9. There are counted as negative because one corner is followed by the 1st character of $s or preceded by the 2nd character of $s. We should modify the script to tolerate one of this cases but not both at the same time. Is that correct?

Comment: That's a toughie... I'm really busy now, but I'll try to figure this out and get back to you in a few of days. Maybe by then a *real* regex ninja will step in and finish it up for you I hope...

Comment: Hi janos, I will try to help you this weekend